# How to Interpolate between all Values in Two Separate Pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

Let's assume you have two Pandas DataFrames, one containing data for the year 2020 and the other containing data for the year 2030.  Both DataFrames have the same shape, column names, and only contain numeric values.  For simplicity, we'll create them as follows:

```
twenty = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1], 'B':[3,3,3]})
thirty = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,3,3], 'B':[7,7,7]})
```

Now, the goal is to perform a linear interpolation on all values in these DataFrames to obtain a new DataFrame for the year 2025 (or whatever year we select).  So, we would want to interpolate between each paired set of values, such as `twenty['A'][0]` and `thirty['A'][0]`.  If we did this for the target year 2025, the result should be:

```
twentyfive = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,2,2],'B':[5,5,5]})
```

I've attempted to use `np.interp`; however, that is really intended for interpolation on a given (singular) array as far as I can tell.  And I've solved the problem using a more brute-force method of melting the DataFrames, adding year columns, merging them together, and then creating a new column with the interpolated values.  It's a bit messy and long-winded.

I feel like there must be a more straight-forward (and optimized) way of performing this task.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `concat` being smart about the keys (naming them integers), and then `groupby` allowing you to interpolate everything:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([twenty, thirty], keys=[20,30], axis=1)
s = (df.groupby(df.columns.get_level_values(1), axis=1)
        .apply(lambda x: x.T.reset_index(1, drop=True).reindex(np.arange(20,31)).interpolate())).T

      20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30
A 0  1.0  1.2  1.4  1.6  1.8  2.0  2.2  2.4  2.6  2.8  3.0
  1  1.0  1.2  1.4  1.6  1.8  2.0  2.2  2.4  2.6  2.8  3.0
  2  1.0  1.2  1.4  1.6  1.8  2.0  2.2  2.4  2.6  2.8  3.0
B 0  3.0  3.4  3.8  4.2  4.6  5.0  5.4  5.8  6.2  6.6  7.0
  1  3.0  3.4  3.8  4.2  4.6  5.0  5.4  5.8  6.2  6.6  7.0
  2  3.0  3.4  3.8  4.2  4.6  5.0  5.4  5.8  6.2  6.6  7.0
```

Now if you just care about 25:

```
s[25].unstack(0)

     A    B
0  2.0  5.0
1  2.0  5.0
2  2.0  5.0
```

Comment: Very clever!  And it gets you all the interim years at once.  Nice idea.

Comment: Though it will likely be fairly slow, given all the groupby reindexing, and interpolation is slow as is. But it extends fairly easily if you have other frames say one that is 33, 39, 59, 97. Can just add them with the proper keys and get everything at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can try of taking average directly, if both have same shape

```
(thirty + twenty)/2
```

Out:

```
    A   B
0   2   5
1   2   5
2   2   5
```

Edit : if the dataframes does not have equal shapes, you can try of merging with inner join and groupby columns to take interpolated mean.

```
df = pd.merge(twenty,thirty, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner').rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
df.T.groupby(df.T.index).mean().T
```

Out:

```
    A   B
0   2   5
1   2   5
2   2   5
```

Comment: Ah, good point.  I'm not sure it's ever occurred to me that you could add, subtract, etc. DataFrames together if they have the same shape; but, it makes sense.  And, to be more general for linear interpolation, instead of dividing by 2 (to get to 2025 in this case), you would multiply the added DataFrames by `(target-2020) / (2030-2020)`.

Comment: Yes, this is probably the best way to go if you have a small number of `DataFrames` and need a simple linear interpolation. Could be more difficult if you had many `DataFrames` and would need to calculate which two need to be used for the averaging of a given year.